# Does $f(g(s))=g(s)$ and $g(f(s))=f(s)$ imply $f(f(s))=f(s)$ and $g(g(s))=g(s)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functional-equations

I have a set $S$ and two one-to-one functions $f:S \to S$ and $g: S \to S$ such that for all $s \in S$ we have $f(g(s))=g(s)$ and $g(f(s))=f(s)$.

If $S$ is infinite, does it follow that $f(f(s))=f(s)$ and $g(g(s))=g(s)$?

If $S$ is finite, then $f$ and $g$ are bijective, so, for instance, $f(f(g(t))=f(g(t))$ follows from the properties and each $s=g(t)$ for some $t$.

But if $S$ is infinite we don't necessarily have a bijection. A concrete counterexample would be nice, if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Start with
$$ g(f(s)) = f(s) $$
use
$$ g(s) = f(g(s)) $$
to substitute the outer $g(s)$ on the LHS.
$$ f(g(f(s))) = f(s) $$
Then use
$$ g(f(s)) = f(s) $$
to substitute the inner $g(f(s))$.
$$ f(f(s)) = f(s) $$
You can do the same with $g$.